# How to submit an application to ubuntu repositories without having to packaging it since i'm not a programmer?

Tags: snap, official-repositories

I'm a physical therapist and would like to submit an application created under the GNU General Public License, version 2. It's called SAPO and you can find the executable jar and the source code [here](http://demotu.org/sapo/).

Many of my colleagues use it in masters and doctorate degree. It's not present in Ubuntu nor Debian and as a Linux entusiast I really would like it to be in both. The main use of SAPO is to assess postural and vertebral column problems. I ask someone who understands of programming to put this software inside Linux repositories. I tried to make the snappy following tutorials but failed. Thank you very much.

Comment: Publish it on github and just let people download it as zip file. Or find someone who can help with packaging. What sort of app is it ? C code ? Python?

Comment: It's in java,  i'm trying to bring my colleagues into linux and it would be much easier if this application was in the ubuntu software center since the physical therapists i know don't understand nothing of programming and far more important than that it could be easily used for everyone worldwide with ubuntu.

Comment: Have you contacted upstream about this? If you still want to do this, I suggest hopping on [rocket chat](https://rocket.ubuntu.com/channel/snapcraft) and asking for help.